# How to create a copy of a PDF file with PDFBox with a filter?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a PDF file file (say A.pdf) and would like to create a copy of that file (B.pdf).
But I would like to skip some text when I copy the file.

For example A.pdf has a text of `Hello World` and I will skip the text `Hello` and eventually B.pdf will have `World` only.

Edit: The word `World` shall stay where it is and it is not going to shift.

I tried to solve that problem using `PDFTextStripper` class but the text remained same. I'm quite new to the PDFBox and using version 2.

Thanks.

Comment: likely tricky. See the RemoveAllText.java example, also have a look at the content stream of the pages of your file with PDFDebugger.

Comment: ... and not only a bit tricky, in particular if you are after a solution for arbitrary documents. By the way, do you expect the "World" to stay in place or shall or shift left to where the "Hello" started?

Comment: @mkl I expect the "World" to stay in place (no shifting). I'll edit the question.

Comment: That's a relevant fact. Depending on how the "Hello World" is drawn, simply removing the "Hello" string will move the "World" part.

Comment: @mkl Naively tried removing text with a sample given in the cookbook. I read many posts on removing text in a Pdf file but I haven't got a concrete example but in the cookbook. Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58501254/1729265) even though your use case is more complicated.