# I Want to Convert PDF TO IMAGE but I only want single output image which contain all the images and Vector graphics only. I do not want text

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox, pdftools

Please suggest how can i achieve this with pdfbox ?

I tried below code :

```
try {
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(inputFilePath));
    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
    
    for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
    { 
        BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);
        ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, outputFilePath + "-" + (page+1) + ".png", 300);
    }
    
    document.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I attached the output i got

See this pic i don't want content:

[![See this pic i don't want content][1]][1]

I am expecting below output, see this pic:

[![see this pic][2]][2]

Comment: Well, you need to use the library to extract the images. You should not print each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step you can remove the text from the PDF. If the text in your PDF is stored in page content streams (and not in some referenced form XObjects or some annotation), you can use the `PdfContentStreamEditor` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58501254/1729265), e.g. like this:

```
PDDocument document = ...;
for (PDPage page : document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages()) {
    PdfContentStreamEditor identity = new PdfContentStreamEditor(document, page) {
        @Override
        protected void write(ContentStreamWriter contentStreamWriter, Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
            String operatorString = operator.getName();

            if (TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS.contains(operatorString))
            {
                return;
            }

            super.write(contentStreamWriter, operator, operands);
        }

        final List<String> TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS = Arrays.asList("Tj", "'", "\"", "TJ");
    };
    identity.processPage(page);
}
```

*([EditPageContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/EditPageContent.java#L256) test `testRemoveTextDocument`)*

If you want the result as a bitmap image, you can now render this document as you did before.

Comment: Great. So, as the answer essentially did give rise to a solution of your issue, you may want to mark it as accepted by selecting the check mark ✔ at its upper left.

Comment: sure and Thanks Again !