# Remove text from a PDF document

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have some PDF files and I have to remove a part of the text, but I can't find out how can I do this. A `PDPageContentStream` does not have any `get` or `remove` methods. Can anyone give me advice or any ideas?
I must use the `PDFBOX` library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace or remove text from PDF with PDFbox in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592078/replace-or-remove-text-from-pdf-with-pdfbox-in-java)

Comment: There is a RemoveAllText.java example in the source code download. However this removes all. You could look with PDFDebugger at the content stream to see if there is some easy way to identify what you want to remove. Or you'll have to use a commercial tool like compart docbridge mill.

Comment: What do you actually mean by removing text? In particular do you hope that the remaining text will reflow? Or do you expect it to remain where it is? Also you say "text" - have you made sure that that "text" is drawn using text drawing instructions? Or does it merely have the look of text and actually is drawn as vector or bitmap images?

Comment: @mkl Yes, it is a text data. I have seen it in the PDFDebugger (Operations Tj and Td). I want to remove the part of the text, and the text that was left must stay in the same place.

Comment: Have you tried the answer @Pino has linked?