# Replace black color in PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to replace the black (0,0,0) color in a PDF file (it's not a spot color with name, it's normal fill color) but I could not find a way to do that yet, could anyone please help me with this?

Attached the PDF file: https://gofile.io/d/AB1Bil

Comment: In this file, you only need to replace "0 0 0 rg" with something else in the content stream. To access the content stream, see the RemoveAllText example. However is this just this file or many others? Are they similar?

Comment: I need to implement the algorithm of replacing the black color in any file not only this file.

Comment: There are so many ways to choose a black color that this would be a major project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making use of the [`PdfContentStreamEditor`](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/PdfContentStreamEditor.java#L36) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58501254/1729265), you can replace the instructions selecting a black'ish RGB color in the page content streams like this:

```java
float[] replacementColor = new float[] {.1f, .7f, .6f};

PDDocument document = ...;
for (PDPage page : document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages()) {
    PdfContentStreamEditor identity = new PdfContentStreamEditor(document, page) {
        @Override
        protected void write(ContentStreamWriter contentStreamWriter, Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
            String operatorString = operator.getName();

            if (RGB_FILL_COLOR_OPERATORS.contains(operatorString))
            {
                if (operands.size() == 3) {
                    if (isApproximately(operands.get(0), 0) &&
                            isApproximately(operands.get(1), 0) &&
                            isApproximately(operands.get(2), 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < replacementColor.length; i++) {
                            operands.set(i, new COSFloat(replacementColor[i]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            super.write(contentStreamWriter, operator, operands);
        }

        boolean isApproximately(COSBase number, float compare) {
            return (number instanceof COSNumber) && Math.abs(((COSNumber)number).floatValue() - compare) < 1e-4;
        }

        final List<String> RGB_FILL_COLOR_OPERATORS = Arrays.asList("rg", "sc", "scn");
    };
    identity.processPage(page);
}
document.save("gridShapesModified-RGBBlackReplaced.pdf");
```

*([EditPageContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/EditPageContent.java#L398) test `testReplaceRGBBlackGridShapesModified`)*

Of course, for your example PDF one could have simply taken the content stream and replaced `0 0 0 rg` by `.1 .7 .6 rg` for the same effect. In general, though, the situation can be more complicated, so I propose this approach.

Beware, though:

- The content stream editor only manipulates the immediate page content stream. But colors can also be set and used in XObjects and patterns used from there. So strictly speaking one has to descent into the XObjects and patterns in the page resources.
- I blindly treat all three-parameter `sc` and `scn` operation as if they set RGB colors. In truth they can also refer to Lab colors and (for `scn`) to Pattern, Separation, DeviceN and ICCBased colors. Strictly speaking on should test the current non-stroking colorspace here.
- I completely ignore that content added over other content with interesting blend modes may result in a displayed color differing from the current fill color.

Comment: Is it also possible to replace black rgb with a separation color ?

Comment: Well, yes, but you have to replace more - above only the color value is exchanged, you'd also need to exchange the color space. And you'd also have to look out for the next color switch; if it merely sets numbers (like **sc**), you'll have to switch back to rgb before.

Comment: Two more small questions regarding your answer. 
Is it possible to set the BlendMode here ? 
Do you have an example to also convert images to another color ?

Comment: For converting colors of bitmap images I'd suggest retrieving the bitmap image in question from the pdf, processing it with some bitmap image manipulation libs, and putting them back into the pdf.

Comment: For setting the blend mode you can simply add an extended graphics state with the desired blend mode to the page resources. Then you can set that graphics state wherever you want by calling `super.write` for it.

Comment: Thx again for your quick answers.
Do you have a code example for the blend mode. This would be realy helpful.

Comment: *"Do you have a code example for the blend mode."* - not yet. I can try and create one later this week but currently I'm here on my smartphone only. Also can you make that a question in its own right, not a mere comment?