# Java-PDFbox: Creating the artifact tag for lines and underlines in tagged PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, tagged-pdf

I am creating the accessibility PDF from the tagged pdf. It shows a "path object is not tagged" error. The PDF has lines and underlined text. So, I am trying to add an "ARTIFACT" tag for the untagged line items. I am able to get the lines from `PDFGraphicsStreamEngine`. Could anyone help me with this?

| PDF Page | PAC3 Error |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Can you share a representative example PDF?

Comment: Hi, I have added the sample PDF here, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z1R-SIalxPzAHH57_Qs0zGPDV3rjoqtN/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`PdfContentStreamEditor`](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/PdfContentStreamEditor.java#L36) class from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58501254/1729265) to edit the page content streams as desired by customizing and calling it like this:

```java
PDDocument document = ...;
for (PDPage page : document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages()) {
    PdfContentStreamEditor markEditor = new PdfContentStreamEditor(document, page) {
        int markedContentDepth = 0;

        @Override
        public void beginMarkedContentSequence(COSName tag, COSDictionary properties) {
            if (inArtifact) {
                System.err.println("Structural error in content stream: Path not properly closed by path painting instruction.");
            }
            markedContentDepth++;
            super.beginMarkedContentSequence(tag, properties);
        }

        @Override
        public void endMarkedContentSequence() {
            markedContentDepth--;
            super.endMarkedContentSequence();
        }

        boolean inArtifact = false;

        @Override
        protected void write(ContentStreamWriter contentStreamWriter, Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
            String operatorString = operator.getName();

            boolean unmarked = markedContentDepth == 0;
            boolean inArtifactBefore = inArtifact;

            if (unmarked && (!inArtifactBefore) && PATH_CONSTRUCTION.contains(operatorString)) {
                super.write(contentStreamWriter, Operator.getOperator("BMC"), Collections.singletonList(COSName.ARTIFACT));
                inArtifact = true;
            }

            super.write(contentStreamWriter, operator, operands);

            if (unmarked && inArtifactBefore && PATH_PAINTING.contains(operatorString)) {
                super.write(contentStreamWriter, Operator.getOperator("EMC"), Collections.emptyList());
                inArtifact = false;
            }
        }

        final List<String> PATH_CONSTRUCTION = Arrays.asList("m", "l", "c", "v", "y", "h", "re");
        final List<String> PATH_PAINTING = Arrays.asList("s", "S", "f", "F", "f*", "B", "B*", "b", "b*", "n");
    };
    markEditor.processPage(page);
}
document.save(...);
```

*([EditMarkedContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/EditMarkedContent.java#L46) test `testMarkUnmarkedPathsAsArtifactsTradeSimple1`)*

The `beginMarkedContentSequence` and `endMarkedContentSequence` overrides track the current marked content nesting depth, in particular whether or not the current content is marked at all.

For yet unmarked instructions the `write` override then encloses unmarked path construction and painting instruction sequences in `/Artifact BMC ... EMC`.

Beware, this code only considers content in page content streams, it does not descend into form XObjects, Patterns, etc.

Furthermore, in case of content streams with errors (e.g. with path construction without painting) this code may add additional errors (e.g. unbalanced marked content starts and ends).

Comment: It shows error in 'Collections.singletonList(COSName.ARTIFACT)' and 'Collections.emptyList()'. PdfContentStreamEditor has "write" function with 'List<COSBase>' argument.

Comment: It doesn't here. I'll add a link to the full source code, maybe you imported a different `Collections` class. It's [EditMarkedContent.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/EditMarkedContent.java#L46).

Comment: Still the error shows - The method write(ContentStreamWriter, Operator, List<COSBase>) in the type PdfContentStreamEditor is not applicable for the arguments 
  (ContentStreamWriter, Operator, List<COSName>)

Comment: Which java version do you use? Your version appears to have less flexible generics resolution. You can try using `Collections.<COSBase>singletonList(COSName.ARTIFACT)` and `Collections.<COSBase>emptyList()` respectively.

Comment: It is working fine now. As you said being used the above lines. I am using java 11.0.11. Thanks a lot. May I know which version you are using and works without any issue.

Comment: Hhmm. My pdfbox playground project was still on Java 1.8. But even after switching to Java 11 the implicit template classes still worked. Admittedly, though, the installed Java 11 is a 11.0.9. But should there be such differences?